# How to dynamically fit a rotated element to the parent element with CSS?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have 2 divs: the `.container` and its child `.element`.
The container is centered on the page, both elements have `position: absolute` and have `vw` and `vh` for width and height.

The difference between them is that the parent element has `25vh` for height and `25vw` for width, however the child element has the opposite: `25vh` for the width and `25vw` for height. This means that the width of one is equivalent to the height of the other.

Then, I used `transform: rotate(90deg)` to rotate the child div. Now they look the same.

I want to move **only the child element** so that it dynamically fits into the parent element. But I'm not getting it done.
I've tried to use positioning properties, transform-origin, translate and so on with percentage or `vw` and `vh` units, but nothing is working.

How to fit this div into the parent div while remaining that way on any screen size?

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
.container {
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  height: 25vh;
  width: 25vw;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #abc;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  height: 25vw;
  width: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider `transform-origin` and some `translation` too

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.container {
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  height: 25vh;
  width: 25vw;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #abc;
  height: 25vw;
  width: 25vh;
  transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```